# Client credentials to get TOKEN of Facebook

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

This page doesn't explains which client credentials we have to use.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
    client_id=YOUR_APP_ID
   &client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET
   &grant_type=client_credentials
```

Any clue what is that?

Does it make sense https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/ also?

Thank you!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
grant_type=client_credentials
```

is just a hardcoded string you should use in your request. You only need to insert your app's id/secret into that string.

Comment: That is not correct, client_credentials is just one of the Oauth2 flows you can use to retrieve tokens. Please refer to the documentation: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-1.3

Comment: "just one of the Oauth2 flows"? I get more confused about what is supposed to go in this line the more I look at it. What are client credentials? Was I given them? Do I request them?

Comment: Is it possible to get FB access_token with permissions using client_credentials method? I successfully received access_token based on my client_id and client_secret, but when I try to access API with this token, I get OAuthException with message that I miss some permissions.